# intelliJ multiple scala-library*.jar file

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I tried to run scala app in IJ community version 2018.3.6, and ran into this error:

```
Error:scalac: Multiple 'scala-library*.jar' files (scala-library-2.12.8.jar, scala-library-2.12.8.jar) in Scala compiler classpath in Scala SDK sbt: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.8:jar
```

and I checked hte .idea/libraries folder saw:
sbt__org_scala_lang_scala_library_2_11_8.jar.xml
sbt__org_scala_lang_scala_library_2_12_8.jar.xml

[image]

after I delete sbt__org_scala_lang_scala_library_2_11_8.jar.xml still got the same error, then i deleted all 2.11.8 scala*.files still got hte same error

I also tried to open the same project in IJ community version 2019.2.4, it complained:

```
Cannot determine module type ("SBT_MODULE") for the following module:
```

there is no 'sbt' tool listed in Preference -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools

anyone know how to get it work?

## FIX

i ended up to uninstall and reinstall Scala plugin in IJ 2019.2.4 to get it working again.

Comment: Do you have Scala plug-in installed in 2019.2.4 version? Did you try importing the project from the `build.sbt` file?

Comment: yes, uninstall then reinstall scala get it working again